# Change ListView layout background color depend on special condition

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I create a `ListView` in a `Fragment` and use a `SimpleAdapter` to set layout and values.

Now I want to change background of a `LinearLayout` in layout that I use in `ListView` depend on the text that sets for `ListView`.
Something like this:

[image: Something Like This]

This is my layout XML.
I want change color of LinearLayout with `list` id.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
    android:layout_height="207dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="193dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/list">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="magnitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fValue"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="region"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sValue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_image"
            android:id="@+id/mImage"
            android:layout_height="143dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in your adapter, check for position and change color of layout. like, if position==0 Color.RED, position==1 COLOR.BLUE

Comment: @Divyesh Thanks, but i want to change it depend on text in textView. But what u say change it depend on position.

Comment: then change using text value for each position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to customize SimpleAdapter by extending SimpleAdapter class and override all required its method.
2. Under getView() method you need to write below code
3. Make sure you set the ID for all  so that you can easily access into java code.
4. Now get the text (color) from textview's text (Like "Green") and set on background color of LinearLayout ( like LinearLayout_Object.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("green"));)

Note : but to get object/value from array/list you need to use "Position" also

Comment: Thanks. Can you write a simple short example, please.

Comment: TextView color = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.colorName);
        LinearLayout viewForColor = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linerLayoutView);
        
        color.setText(list.get(position).getColorName());
        viewForColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color.getText().toString()));
        //Or
        viewForColor.setBackgroundColor(list.get(position).getColorName());

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the condition in your adapter for text and then set the background color of linear layout.

For example:

```
if(textView.getText().toString().equals("red"))
{
      linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(your color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my `adapter` I do it this way:

```
row = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llListViewRow);

row.setBackgroundColor(rowBgColor(position));
```

EDIT:
in case you want to change color depending on TextView:

```
row = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llListViewRow);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);

row.setBackgroundColor(rowBgColor(tv.getText()));
```

where `rowBgColor()` should be your method returning the required color based on the text in TextView

Answer (score 1):

you can try to like this hope this can help you..

```
  if (yourmodel.get(postion).getTextName().equalsIgnoreCase("RED")) {
        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    } else if (yourmodel.get(postion).getTextName().equalsIgnoreCase("GREEN")) {
        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
    } else if (yourmodel.get(postion).getTextName().equalsIgnoreCase("YELLOW")) {
        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
    } else {
        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2F00FF"));
    }
```

Comment: What is `yourmodel`?